# jQuery: hierarchical tabs ui

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to create hierarchal tabs ui using jQuery, but my code result gets the second hierarchy doesn't display.

[my result here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsshinya/fSnTm/)

This is my code

HTML

```
<div class="itemListContainer">
<ul id="itemListNav">
    <li class="current"><a class="heading active" href="#sec1">Section 1</a>
        <ul id="secMenus">
            <li><a href="#list1">List 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#list2">List 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#list3">List 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a class="heading" href="#sec2">Section 2</a>
        <ul id="secMenus">
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a class="heading" href="#sec3">Section 3</a>
        <ul id="secMenus">
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a class="heading" href="#sec4">Section 4</a>
        <ul id="secMenus">
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul><!-- end #itmeListNav -->

<div class="itemList">
    <div id="sec1">
        <p>text1</p>
        <div id="list1">
            text list1
        </div>
        <div id="list2">
            text list2
        </div>
        <div id="list3">
            text list3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sec2">
        <p>text2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sec3">
        <p>text3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sec4">
        <p>text4</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- end .itemList -->
    <div class="giftsSpecificArea">

    </div><!-- end .giftsSpecificArea -->
```

CSS

```
/* General Utilities */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}

q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

/* itemListContainer */
.itemListContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
}

#itemListNav {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    margin-right: 1.69492%;
}

.itemList {
    float: left;
    width: 68.30508%;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("ul#itemListNav li ul:not(:first)").hide(); // display only the first menus groups

/* control itemListNav */
$( "ul#itemListNav a.heading" ).click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline', 'none');
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('slow', function() {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
        });
    } else {
        $('ul#itemListNav li.current ul').slideUp('slow', function() {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
        });
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
        });
    }
    return false;
});

// 1st hierarchical contents displays at itemList  
$(".itemList div:not("+$("ul#itemListNav li a.active").attr("href")+")").hide(); // display only the first menus groups contents

    $("ul#itemListNav li a").click(function() {
        $("ul#itemListNav li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".itemList div").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
        return false;
    });
```

// The 2nd hierarchical contents displays at itemList
    $(".itemList div#sec1 div:not("+$("ul#secMenus li a.active").attr("href")+")").hide();

```
    $("ul#secMenus li a").click(function() {
        $("ul#secMenus li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#sec1 div").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
        return false;
    });
```

}); // end script

please, give me any tips.
Thank you!

Comment: could you please just explain your issue? When u wanna display second hierarchy?

Comment: @Pitchai thank you for your comments. I want to display the first hierarchy as content type menus, and these have some categories menus which we've called the second hierarchy. For example, a user clicks content type menu is called 'foo', which has three categories such as 'bar', 'buzz', and 'bazz'. At first, itemList shows all items of 'foo' including all categories. Then, this user has interest of the category 'buzz', so click it. As the result, itemList display only items of 'buzz'.

Comment: I saw your fiddle and it seems like it works as you expect. U might have corrected that. Still u have issue?

Comment: @Pitchai if you click on list1 of section1, you can't see anything in itemList.

Comment: move the content divs of sub menu items outside from the content div of main menu. Then it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<div id="sec1">
  <p>text1</p>
  <div id="list1">text list1</div>
  <div id="list2">text list2</div>
  <div id="list3">text list3</div>
</div>
```

TO

```
<div id="sec1">
  <p>text1</p>
 </div>
 <div id="list1">text list1</div>
 <div id="list2">text list2</div>
 <div id="list3">text list3</div>
```

Because, as you hide the parent div, it wouldn't show the inner div.